# ¿ Por qué sigo teniendo error de CORS policy con node/express y Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Con **Angular** le envio la data a **node/express**. Despues **node/express** debe enviar esta data a la **api mercadopago**. Estaba teniendo error de **CORS policy**, buscando informacion encontre que debia agregar estas lineas en **node/express**:

```js
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
```

pero desde **Angular** en la consola sigue mostrando el mismo error de **CORS policy**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aca envio la data desde ANGULAR**.

```js
sendData() {
    // creo array de compra
    let compra: Compramp[] = [];
    for (let book of this.bookList) {
      compra.push({
        title: book.name,
        unit_price: book.price,
        quantity: book.quantity
      });    
    }
    // aca servicio mercadopago
    this.mercadopagoService.checkout(compra).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.error('Error al recibir la data de compra en el servidor. ' + err)
    );
  }
```

mi servicio **mercadopago.service.ts**

```js
private SERVER = 'http://localhost:3000/checkout';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    if (!isDevMode()) {
      this.SERVER = 'https://bookstore-cds-server.herokuapp.com';
    }
  }

  checkout(compra: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.SERVER}`, compra);
  }
```

**Aca NODE/EXPRESS**

**ruta**

```js
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = Router();
import { checkout } from '../controllers/mercadopago.controller';

router.post('/checkout', checkout);
```

Aca el controlador **mercadopago.controller** donde recibe la data desde **Angular** para hacer un **redirect** a la **api**.

```js
// SDK de Mercado Pago
const mercadopago = require("mercadopago");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

import { Compramp } from "../compramp";

import { Request, Response } from "express";

mercadopago.configure({
  // el token es el de "produccion" que te da mercadopago, seria el token del vendedor el que recibe la plata.
  access_token:
    "APP_USR-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx",
});

export const checkout = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next
): Promise<Response> => {

  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 'error',
      error: 'req body cannot be empty',
    });
  }
  
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  
  let compra = [
    {
      title: "",
      unit_price: 0,
      quantity: 0,
    },
  ];

  let items: Compramp[] = [];

  compra = req.body; // obtengo la data

  for (let data of compra) {
    items.push({
      title: data.title,
      unit_price: parseInt(data.unit_price.toString()),
      quantity: parseInt(data.quantity.toString()),
    });
  }

  try {

    let preference = {
      items,
    };

    mercadopago.preferences
      .create(preference)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body);
        // redirije a pagina de mercadopago 'https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/checkout/v1/redirect?pref_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'
        res.redirect(response.body.init_point);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
 
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json("Internal server error");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ npm install cors
```

Instala cors en tu nodejs e importa de tu archivo principal index.js o app.js  habilitando de manera global como middlewar usando `app.use(cors())` :

```
 var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar colocando en tu archivo html principal esto dentro de la etiqueta `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
```

Del lado del servidor *(Express)* te recomiendo usar https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
Puedes implementarlo de la siguiente manera

```
app.use(
        cors({
            origin: function (origin, callback) {
                if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
                // Dirección desde donde se pueden hacer peticiones
                if (!["http://localhost:3000"].includes(origin)) {
                    return callback(new Error(`La política CORS para el origen ${origin} no permiten el acceso al servidor.`), false);
                }
                return callback(null, true);
            }
        })
    )
```

Puedes checar información más detallada sobre errores cors aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta....acabo de hacer lo que publicaste,pero por consola desde node sale este error: Error: La política CORS para este origen no permite el acceso desde el origen en particular.

Comment: y este error desde la consola de Angular:  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/checkout' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: El primer error es porque no está permitiendo la conexión a tu servidor desde otra dirección diferente a "http://localhost:3000" edité mi respuesta para que añadas en el array las direcciones permitidas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero sigo teniendo el mismo error de CORS policy